# Count instances of a random number of n length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe column containing numbers of varying length. I want to count how many instances of a six digit number I have in a column, regardless of which numbers and their order.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"number": [1234, 12345, 777777, 949494, 22, 987654]})
```

Should return that there is **three** instances of a six digit number in the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert it to string, check the length of the string and sum those which length is 6:

```
(df['number'].astype(str).apply(len) == 6).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `np.log10` and floor division which gives you order of magnitude for numbers. Then check how many satisfy that condition.

```
N = 6
(np.log10(df['number'])//1).eq(N-1).sum()
#3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.ceil` and `np.log10`:

```
df['length'] = np.ceil(np.log10(df['number']))
```

Result:

```
   number  length
0    1234     4.0
1   12345     5.0
2  777777     6.0
3  949494     6.0
4      22     2.0
5  987654     6.0
```

To count instances use:

```
np.ceil(np.log10(df['number'])).eq(6).sum()
```

Valid only for values > 0.